# Don't match specific pattern in Regexp Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a mongodb query that may contain dynamic values for example

```
[{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}},{$out:'newc'},{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }}]
[{$group: { _id: '$browser', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}},{$out:'deffC'}]
```

I want always match everything without `,{$out:'anything'}`

End result is

```
[{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}},{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }}]
[{$group: { _id: '$browser', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}}]
```

Comment: [You should not parse JSON with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/6320039) (this is for XML, but applies for json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex to match that string is this: `/,\{\$out:'.*'\}/g`

```js
let s = `[{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}},{$out:'newc'},{$group: { _id: '$os_name', count: { $sum: 1 } }}]
         [{$group: { _id: '$browser', count: { $sum: 1 } }},{$sort:{count:-1}},{$out:'deffC'}]`;

s = s.replace(/,\{\$out:'.*'\}/g, '');

console.log(s);
```